# Make Doxygen document a struct/class defined inside a macro call

Tags: class, macros, struct, call, doxygen

I have this [`PACKED` macro](https://github.com/marciof/Eon/blob/master/library/util.h#L207), that receives a [`struct` definition](https://github.com/marciof/Eon/blob/master/core/architecture/x86/multiboot/Boot_Device.h#L21) and returns it with a compiler annotation to make it packed.

For example:

```
/**
 * ...
 */
PACKED(struct A {
    /**
     * ...
     */
    int x;
});
```

I have tried several Doxygen options to include that documentation, but I've had no success so far. Closest I've come up with is this:

```
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING = YES
PREDEFINED = PACKED(type)=type
MACRO_EXPANSION = YES
```

But that messes up the `struct` and members' documentation (confirmed via `doxygen -d Preprocessor`).

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's a [bug in Doxygen](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=686983).

One possible workaround is to use `@class`, and so on.